# ValueError parsing time string

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have written this code to convert a unusual time into EPOCH:

```
x = 'Mon Jul 25 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016'
print(datetime.strptime(x, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y').strftime('%s'))
```

However, it returns the error `ValueError: time data 'Mon Jul 25 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y'`

The problem is something to do with the timezone. What have I done wrong?

Comment: UTC offset must be in the form +HHMM or -HHMM, yours is +HH:MM.

Answer (score 3):

Your timezone format has an extra `:` inside which causes the format mismatching error, you can remove the last `:` from the string firstly and then parse it:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
x1 = re.sub(r":(?=[^:]+$)", "", x)   # remove the last semi colon

datetime.strptime(x1, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y').strftime('%s')
# '1469487870'
```

Comment: Interestingly, this works in Python3, but in Python2, this fails with: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y'`

Answer (score 2):

If you use dateutil instead of datetime.strptime it seems to work:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Mon Jul 25 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016")
>> datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 25, 19, 4, 30, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -3600))
```