# Optimise Python Code

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I have written the following code to preprocess a dataset like this:

```
StartLocation   StartTime   EndTime
school          Mon Jul 25 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016  Mon Jul 25 19:04:33 GMT+01:00 2016
...             ...         ...
```

It contains a list of locations attended by a user with the start and end time. Each location may occur several times and there is no comprehensive list of locations. From this, I want to aggregate data for each location (frequency, total time, mean time). To do this I have written the following code:

```
def toEpoch(x):
    try:
        x = datetime.strptime(re.sub(r":(?=[^:]+$)", "", x), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y').strftime('%s')
    except:
        x = datetime.strptime(x, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y').strftime('%s')
    x = (int(x)/60)
    return x

#Preprocess data
df = pd.read_csv('...')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['StartTime'][index] = toEpoch(df['StartTime'][index])
    df['EndTime'][index] = toEpoch(df['EndTime'][index])
    df['TimeTaken'][index] = int(df['EndTime'][index]) - int(df['StartTime'][index])
total = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).sum()
av = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).mean()
count = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).count()
output = pd.DataFrame({"location": total.index, 'total': total['TimeTaken'], 'mean': av['TimeTaken'], 'count': count['TimeTaken']})
print(output)
```

This code functions correctly, however is quite inefficient. How can I optimise the code?

EDIT: Based on [@Batman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3734914/batman) helpful comments I no longer iterate. However, I still hope to further optimise this if possible. The updated code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...')
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(toEpoch)
df['EndTime'] = df['EndTime'].apply(toEpoch)
df['TimeTaken'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']
total = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).sum()
av = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).mean()
count = df.groupby(df['StartLocation'].str.lower()).count()
output = pd.DataFrame({"location": total.index, 'total': total['TimeTaken'], 'mean': av['TimeTaken'], 'count': count['TimeTaken']})
print(output)
```

Comment: you should group only once and then get `sum`, `mean` and `count`

Comment: do you really need to `.str.lower()` ? do you really need regex ?

Comment: @furas The locations are manually entered so it's necessary and the regex is to deal with the unusual time stamp used. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782874/valueerror-parsing-time-string))

Comment: using `apply` is still iterating.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd do is stop iterating over the rows.

```
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(toEpoch)
df['EndTime'] = df['EndTime'].apply(toEpoch)
df['TimeTaken'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']
```

Then, do a single `groupby` operation.

```
gb = df.groupby('StartLocation')
total = gb.sum()
av = gb.mean()
count = gb.count()
```

Comment: Am I also able to calculate the time taken without iterating?

Comment: @user7347576 yes `df['TimeTaken'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']` (if you have numbers in `EndTime` and `StartTime`)

Comment: @Batman Can I also lower all text to lowercase prior to grouping efficiently?

Comment: Sure. Use `df['StartLocation'].apply(str.lower)`.

Comment: @Batman Am not sure why, but the lower doesn't always seem to work. In my final output it produces 'living room', 'Living room' and 'Living Room.' Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you assigning the output? I.e. `df['StartLocation'] = df['StartLocation'].apply(str.lower)`

Answer (score 2):

- vectorize the date conversion
- take the difference of two series of timestamps gives a series of timedeltas
- use `total_seconds` to get the seconds from the the timedeltas
- `groupby` with `agg`

---

```
# convert dates
cols = ['StartTime', 'EndTime']
df[cols] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols].stack()).unstack()

# generate timedelta then total_seconds via the `dt` accessor
df['TimeTaken'] = (df.EndTime - df.StartTime).dt.total_seconds()

# define the lower case version for cleanliness
loc_lower = df.StartLocation.str.lower()

# define `agg` functions for cleanliness
# this tells `groupby` to use 3 functions, sum, mean, and count
# it also tells what column names to use
funcs = dict(Total='sum', Mean='mean', Count='count')
df.groupby(loc_lower).TimeTaken.agg(funcs).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

***explanation of date conversion***

- I define `cols` for convenience
- `df[cols] =` is an assignment to those two columns
- `pd.to_datetime()` is a vectorized date converter but only takes `pd.Series` not `pd.DataFrame`
- `df[cols].stack()` makes the 2-column dataframe into a series, now ready for `pd.to_datetime()`
- use `pd.to_datetime(df[cols].stack())` as described and `unstack()` to get back my 2-columns and now ready to be assigned.

Comment: Could you please explain what this does?

Comment: @user7347576 explained :-)

Comment: @piRSqaured I don't mean to waste your time, but I still don't understand why this would be faster and where I would use it?

Comment: @user7347576 no worries. I left out details because I'm off to donate stuff at goodwill. I assumed you'd make a leap and see what to do. That's my fault. I'll show you what to do in an hour or so

Comment: @user7347576 there you go.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @piRsquaed This produces unusual values. eg. one of the means should be 9.527778 but this approach produces 9.500000e-09.

Comment: @user7347576 typically we refer posters to [this article about MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It helps prevent issues similar to this where we are discussing issues that are most likely explained in the data.  You should consider editing your question providing more example data and the results you expect to see.  In particular, show me the example data that gives you the results you're referring to.  Otherwise, there are simply too many variables to unwind.